# Docker: Rerun some build steps only

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am fairly new to Docker and I am running into a bit of an issue. For my application I need to get some dependencies in the dockerfile, which take some time to install. The dockerfile essentially looks like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN <time-consuming dependency installation>
COPY . /app
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

When I make a small change to my code I would like to be able to re-run the container without installing everything again, but rebuilding still uses the old code. Rebuilding without cache works, but takes ~10 minutes (and unnecessary bandwidth) to install.

Is there a way to use cache for every EXCEPT the COPY step? Alternatively, could I save a plain image with just the dependencies?

The docker-compose.yaml looks like:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  my-app:
    build:
      context: '.'
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:80:8000"
```

To build I am doing

```
docker-compose down
docker-compose build
docker-compose up
```

But it only works if I add `--no-cache` to the build command.

Comment: Are you using different tag name every time ? This might help - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=prlixoDIfrc

Comment: I am using docker-compose, and the tag/name are the same every time. Would this be an issue?

Comment: I am new to the docket as well and had the same issue. The above video helped me.

Comment: The `COPY` line should invalidate the cache for everything after it, if any file in the local tree has changed.  How are you starting the container?  (Can you include the relevant part of your `docker-compose.yml` file?)

Comment: @DavidMaze I added the docker-compose.yml 
I am starting the container by doing `docker-compose up`, I have also tried doing `docker-compose down` and `build` first with no luck

Comment: You're already doing the right thing. With this setup each run step should be cached in a separate layer. Only the copy should be rerun.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your Dockerfile, your `RUN` command should often be cached

Comment: It is cached, however the COPY step does not COPY new files in unless I use the --no-cache option. My understanding is that COPY should not cache, but it seems to be doing so.

Comment: `COPY` will be cached if you have no new files. Otherwise, it will not be cached. It will also be helpful if you include the command you used to build in your questions

Comment: How about you try adding `WORKDIR /app` then just `COPY . .`